# Probability of winning a tennis game after a point has been played?

Tags: probability

Player A and B both have equal chance of winning any given point regardless of who's serving, so there is a 0.5 probability for either of them to win any point and therefore the game. My question is if Player A wins the first point and goes 15-0 up (as per the tennis scoring system) what are their chances of winning the game? Also what about if Player A is 30-15 up, or 40-15 up?

Thanks for any help, James

Comment: Do you think that the winning of one point affects the probability of winning another, or are they entirely independent?

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy but tedious to build the (sparse) transition matrix $P$ of an absorbing Markov chain that represents a tennis game, with each state corresponding to a possible score and fixed probabilities $p$ of player A winning a point and $q=1-p$ of player B winning a point. For example, if the first state corresponds to 0-0, then the first row will have $p$ in the column that corresponds to 15-0 and $q$ in the column that corresponds to 0-15. There will be, if I’m not mistaken, 20 states. The last two states should be winning and losing so that this matrix is in *canonical form*.

Once you have the transition matrix $P$, compute its *fundamental matrix* $N=(I-Q)^{-1}$, where $Q$ is the upper-left $18\times18$ submatrix consisting of the non-absorbing states (i.e., everything but win and lose). This is not a pleasant calculation to do by hand, so I suggest using an online matrix calculator of some sort (e.g., Wolfram|Alpha can do this for you). Once you have $N$, you can easily answer your questions and many others. For example, the chance of A’s winning if the score is 15-0 is given by the product of the row of $N$ that corresponds to this score and the “win” column of $P$. (By my calculations, with $p=\frac12$, this is ${21\over32}$).